# creating a copy of a file with different name in bash

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu

I have a filename stored in `$file`.

I need to delete some contents from that file for some calculation. But the original file should not be modified. So I am looking for a way to create a duplicate copy of that file to modify, and then delete it later. Is there a way to create a file with command like `"$filename+2"` or something like that? How do I go about doing this?

Comment: what about `cp ${filename} ${filename}.copy`?

Comment: was looking for something like this. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **cp** as already mentioned but consider using **mktemp** to create the temp filename.